# How to return an Ajax result using async/await?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

Trying to get familiar with `async/await`, I've tried the following code in Chrome:

```
async function f() { 
     return await $.get('/');
};
var result = f();
```

but `result` doesn't hold the result (string); rather it holds a `Promise` which needs to be awaited again. This code does give me the response string:

```
var response = await $.get('/');
```

How can I return the actual response string from a function using await?

Comment: async/await doesn't magically solve the return from asynchronous function problem. Somewhere, you'll still have to wait on the result. In this case, you need a `.then()` on `result`.

Comment: `var result = await f();` will work pretty

Answer (score 34, accepted):

either

```
function f() { 
  return $.get('/');
};

async test() {
  var x = await f()
  console.log(x)
}

test()
```

or

```
f().then(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
}
```

the `async/await` is just another way to write the same logic.

Comment: so what does the extra await I put in f() does?

Comment: @user3599803 what do you mean?

Comment: in my code above, I wrote `return await $.get('/');` inside `f()`, is this await is useless?

Comment: yes, this await has no effect when you call the `f()` method. If you'd like to write further code lines inside of `f()` your await would make sense: `f() { 
     let res = await $.get('/'); console.log(res)
};`

Answer (score 6):

`await` and `async` are basically just syntactical sugar on top of `Promise`. If you end up with a `Promise` at the end, you still need to treat it like a `Promise`.

```
const response = f().then(() => { });
```

Or, if you are calling it inside of an async function, you can await to resolve it:

```
async function main() {
  const response = await f();
  console.log(response);
}
```

A pattern I like to use is have my main code wrapped in a self-executing async function, so I can still use await:

```
(async () => {
  const result = await doSomething();
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Note that even with that pattern, I need a final `catch()` to catch any errors it may have that aren't caught otherwise:

```
(async () => {
  // blah blah
})().catch(() => {});
```

Answer (score -1):

The return type of async functions is Promise. So you will have to await or then() to get the result.