# Wait for a normal function to complete before proceeding further?

Tags: javascript

I want the program to wait till `getFiles` returns the array and it should get concatenated before printing array named `totalProjectFiles`.

```js
let totalProjectFiles = []
let projectDir = './defaults/'

    function getFiles (dir, files_){
        files_ = files_ || [];
        var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
        for (var i in files){
            var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
            if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()){
                getFiles(name, files_);
            } else {
                files_.push(name);
            }
        }
        return(files_)
    }




function ff (){
  const a = getFiles(projectDir)
  totalProjectFiles.concat(a)

  console.log(totalProjectFiles)
}

ff()
```

Comment: please note that getFiles() doesn't return a promise. It's just a normal function that returns an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return an Ajax result using async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506445/how-to-return-an-ajax-result-using-async-await)

Comment: that would be the default behavior of js if getFiles isn't asynchronous. What are you seeing? You might want to share that function with us.

Comment: @HariKrishnan That comment should be part of the question. Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: @messerbill Read the comment right above yours.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  I have edited the question, can you please help.

Comment: You've given us very little to go on, and have changed the question from its original, which is considered bad form. That said, when I run this in node, adding the appropriate `const fs = require('fs');` to it, it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. I would recommend checking the docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

You just need an `await`

```
async function ff (){
  const a = await getFiles(projectDir)
  totalProjectFiles.concat(a)

  console.log(totalProjectFiles)
}
```

Comment: could you share the function or a scenario that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @HariKrishnanH Please edit your question to include the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
let totalProjectFiles = []

async function ff (){
  const a = await getFiles(projectDir)
  totalProjectFiles.concat(a)

  console.log(totalProjectFiles)
}

ff()
```

Comment: getFiles() doesnot return a promise. It's just a normal function, that return an array.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

> please add await inside to async fuction

let totalProjectFiles = []

```
async function ff (){
  const a = await  getFiles(projectDir)
  totalProjectFiles.concat(a)

  console.log(totalProjectFiles)
}

ff()
```

Answer (score 0):

Concat return a new array not mutate it assign it back

```
function ff (){
  const a = getFiles(projectDir)
  totalProjectFiles = totalProjectFiles.concat(a)

  console.log(totalProjectFiles)
}
```

Comment: still its printing a blank array [ ] , but a is receiving the value.

Comment: There is a reason why its not working.
`totalProjectFiles.concat(a)` will return a new array not mutate totalProjectFiles and so you are getting empty array
so use `totalProjectFiles = totalProjectFiles.concat(a)` and issue solved