# Why is chartjs treating these arrays differently?

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

I'm using [ChartJS](https://chartjs.org) to build a line graph. The data is coming from an API. I take the data points from the API and use the `push` method to build an array to be used in the parameters of ChartJS `data: { data: dataFromAPI`. I'm using AJAX to `GET` data from the API.

When I do this:

```
var someArray = [23,49,39,59];
```

and input it into the `data: { data:` parameter, it works. In the console, `someArray` looks like this

```
Array(4) [23,49,39,59]
```

When I use the `push` method in the AJAX call, the array looks like this in the console:

```
Array []
```

Both array variables are being declared globally.

The array that I'm using the `push` method to build in the AJAX call does not work with ChartJS. It produces this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: n[a]._view is undefined`

What is the difference between, what I would refer to as a manually typed array, and the array that `push` built? And how come ChartJS does not want to accept `push` array?

I would also like to note that `Array []` does have elements inside.

Comment: Have you thought about building up an array using push(), and then assigning the whole array to your chartObject.data.data ? I don't know why this is happening, but could be to do with how the accessor is exposed for the "data" field.

Comment: I will try this, thank you.

Comment: Did not work. Although it cleared the errors in the console, the chart remains data-less.

Comment: @LaravelSucks can you share your code? might be easier for people to understand your problem that way.

Answer (score 1):

I completely neglected the asynchronous nature of AJAX, and did not enclose my script in an `async` call. This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506445/how-to-return-an-ajax-result-using-async-await) question/answer provided me with enough insight to move on. It should be noted that global arrays behavior differently when they are assigned values inside a scoped function.